# Envio de Email com PHP

Tags: php, email, smtp

Estou com um site onde o servidor acabou de bloquear o envio de e-mail  de outro provedor, só permitindo o envio com o e-mail do próprio domínio, eu fiz a alteração do FROM para um e-mail do meu domínio e funcionou, porem o e-mail recebido aparece com o remetente esse e-mail que eu alterei, eu gostaria de saber se tem como alterar para aparecer o e-mail preenchido no formulário, lembrando que tem que ser só na visualização, pois o envio tem que ser com o e-mail do provedor pois outro é bloqueado, segue o código que estou utilizando:

```
<?php

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
$msg = $_POST['mensagem'];

$to = "rogerio.santana@hospitalsantatereza.com.br";

$subject = "Formulário de Contato";

$menssage = "<strong> Nome: </strong> $nome <br/><br/> <strong> E-mail: </strong> $email <br/><br/> <strong> Assunto: </strong> $assunto <br/><br/> <strong> Mensagem: </strong> $msg";

$header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$header .= "From: $to\n";

mail($to, $subject, $menssage, $header);

echo "Mensagem enviada com sucesso";

?>
```

Comment: Tenta imprimir o que a variável $email está recebendo. Para ter certeza que a informação que está chegando no seu php está correta.

echo $email;

Comment: $email é o que vem do formulário, antes estava configurado para a variável $to receber essa informação, mas ao mudarem a configuração do servidor começou a apresentar erro de autorização, tive que mudar o $to para um e-mail do domínio, mas queria que continuasse a aparecer no remetente o conteúdo do $email

Answer (score 2):

Tenta testar assim:

```
<?php

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
$msg = $_POST['mensagem'];

$to = "rogerio.santana@hospitalsantatereza.com.br";

$subject = "Formulário de Contato";

$menssage = "<strong> Nome: </strong> $nome <br/><br/> <strong> E-mail: </strong> $email <br/><br/> <strong> Assunto: </strong> $assunto <br/><br/> <strong> Mensagem: </strong> $msg";

$emailsender = "email@seu-dominio.com";

$header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$header .= "From: $to\n";

mail($to, $subject, $menssage, $header, "-r".$emailsender);

echo "Mensagem enviada com sucesso";

?>
```

De atenção especial a variável **$emailsender**, nela você deve colocar um e-mail existente em seu domínio, exemplo: rogerio.santana@hospitalsantatereza.com.br.

Outra observação: 
Em Linux é obrigatório o uso do parâmetro -r (concatenação do "From na linha de envio") devido ao envio ser feito através do Postfix.

Qualquer dúvida, só falar.

Comment: O código do jeito que esta funciona, fiz a alteração que você falou e continuou a funcionar, o que eu gostaria de mudar é o seguinte, do jeito que esta o remetente da mensagem é o $to, no caso o rogerio.santana@hospitalsantatereza,com.br eu gostaria que ele fosse o $email que é o campo que vem do formulário, na King Host isso é bloqueado eu não consigo falar que o $to é um e-mail qualquer ele necessariamente tem que ser um e-mail do domínio, mas eu queria que pelo menos a visualização fosse o e-mail do formulário, queria saber se tem como fazer isso

Comment: Entendi, no caso vc já tentou add `$headers .= 'From: Suporte <email@dominio.com.br>' . "\r\n";`

Comment: Mesma coisa, no caso o From eu tenho que usar um e-mail do domínio, mas eu queria que o e-mail recebido fosse da pessoa que preencheu o formulário, ele fica assim:

De: rogerio.santana@hospitalsantatereza.com.br [mailto:rogerio.santana@hospitalsantatereza.com.br] 
Enviada em: quarta-feira, 18 de janeiro de 2017 12:39
Para: rogerio.santana@hospitalsantatereza.com.br
Assunto: Hospital Santa Tereza - Formulario de Contato

Nome: Rogério do Carmo Santana 

E-mail: rogeriosantan@yahoo.com.br 

Assunto: Sugestões 

Mensagem: teste

Comment: Eu queria que esse campo De: fosse o e-mail do cliente que preencheu o formulário, igual a gente faz com Outlook quando envia um e-mail utilizando outra caixa mudando só o "Para:" algo desse tipo

Eu add uma linha 
$header .= implode ( "\n",array ( "From: $to", "Reply-To: $email", "Return-Path: $email","MIME-Version: 1.0","X-Priority: 3","Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" ) );

Que faz com que ao responder ele já preencha o responder com o e-mail correto, mas ainda não é o ideial